# How to increase the Quality of the camera using AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, camera

I'm trying for a webcam based application. I started the code like this:

```
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Video;
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
a.vid1.attachCamera(cam);
a.vid1.smoothing = true;
```

My problem is that the quality of the video.
Im using an iMac machine, in which camera quality is good.
Is there any way to increase the quality of the camera output?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a sample code

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.ActivityEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;

    public class iosTest extends Sprite
    {

        private var cam:Camera;
        private var vid:Video;


        public function iosTest()
        {
            super();

            // support autoOrients
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            cam = Camera.getCamera();

            if (!cam) 
            {
                trace("No camera is installed.");
            }
            else 
            {
                connectCamera();
            }
        }

        private function connectCamera():void 
        {
            cam.setMode(640, 480, 25); 
            cam.setQuality(0,100);
            vid             = new Video();
            vid.width       = cam.width;
            vid.height      = cam.height; 
            vid.attachCamera(cam);
            addChild(vid);    

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        }

        private function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {

            return;

            switch (cam.width) {
                case 160:
                    cam.setMode(320, 240, 10); 
                    break;
                case 320:
                    cam.setMode(640, 480, 5); 
                    break;
                default:
                    cam.setMode(160, 120, 15); 
                    break;
            } 
            removeChild(vid);           
            connectCamera();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, though why do you randomly have super() there?

Comment: It is better sometimes to have it than not. Maybe not needed in this case but I am used to always write it in constructor.

Comment: Fair enough.. super() is normally only required if you're marking a method for override.

Comment: yes... in this case you overwrite the Sprite constructor. indeed it does nothing...

Comment: The super() call will in fact be added for you if you don't explicitly put it there. It *has* to be in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`setQuality()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Camera.html#setQuality%28%29)

> **Parameters**
>
> **bandwidth:int** — Specifies the maximum
>   amount of bandwidth that the current
>   outgoing video feed can use, in bytes
>   per second. To specify that Flash
>   Player video can use as much bandwidth
>   as needed to maintain the value of
>   quality, pass 0 for bandwidth. The
>   default value is 16384.
> **quality:int**
>   — An integer that specifies the
>   required level of picture quality, as
>   determined by the amount of
>   compression being applied to each
>   video frame. Acceptable values range
>   from 1 (lowest quality, maximum
>   compression) to 100 (highest quality,
>   no compression). To specify that
>   picture quality can vary as needed to
>   avoid exceeding bandwidth, pass 0 for
>   quality.

Comment: @Marty... I tried that with setQuality command.Same output. Output was pixelated. Also i applied vid1.smoothing = true; which resulted in blur, of course loss of quality.

Comment: I don't think you can increase the quality beyond what this method can offer.