# How can access iPhone camera with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm a newbie with flash AS3. And I'd like to create app with air for ios.
how can I access iPhone camera with air and use library ( ASFEAT and Away3D ) for create AR app. I want to see example code for use, please

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard way to get it

[Is there any other alternate ways to access camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339871/is-there-any-other-alternate-ways-to-access-camera/6340053#6340053)

Also read about native api provided by ios to air.