# flex mobile camera size

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I am capturing camera on flex for android using air 3.1
and found that the camera is only showing the a part of of actual camera video.
When i view camera using normal camera application in android galaxy tab, it shows full camera area but when i am capturing the camera in flex its showing only the center area for it.

I tried using setMode to set the resolution, but its not of any use.

Is there any way to get full camera area captured inside flex using camera.getCamera ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I retagged the question to remove references to Flex because it's not really an issue w/ the Flex Framework.  You really should attach some code to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this post can help you [How to increase the Quality of the camera using AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339398/how-to-increase-the-quality-of-the-camera-using-as3/6340091#6340091)

Since you did not posted any code in how to set the scaleMode here is some code

```
// support autoOrients
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
cam = Camera.getCamera();

cam.setMode(640, 480, 25); 
cam.setQuality(0,100);
vid             = new Video();
vid.width       = cam.width;
vid.height      = cam.height; 
vid.attachCamera(cam);
addChild(vid);
```