# webcam resolution on mac

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex4

I have an adobe air app that runs on windows. I got it running on Mac but the webcam resolution is bad. Im using logitech quickcam pro 9000. on windows it is HD. in mac, it looks like a cheap webcam. surprisingly, the built in apple photo booth software displays a much better resolution using the same webcam. im using mac osx lion. is there hope? I dont see a mac driver for this particular webcam.

My code:

```
camera = Camera.getCamera();    
camera.setQuality(0, 100); 
camera.setMode(640, 480, 30, true);
camera.setMotionLevel(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to set the video width and height to the camera.width and camera.height propertie also set the FPS to 15 i think 30 FPS is too much for the camera.

Comment: fps should not be an issue 'til 30

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer on this similar question

[How to increase the Quality of the camera using AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339398/how-to-increase-the-quality-of-the-camera-using-as3/6340091#6340091)

Try to get the max size out of your camera and set the quality to highest value.
Hope that helps.

PS: short code

```
    private function connectCamera():void 
    {
        cam.setMode(640, 480, 25); 
        cam.setQuality(0,100);
        vid             = new Video();
        vid.width       = cam.width;
        vid.height      = cam.height; 
        vid.attachCamera(cam);
        addChild(vid);    

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
    }

    private function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {

        return;

        switch (cam.width) {
            case 160:
                cam.setMode(320, 240, 10); 
                break;
            case 320:
                cam.setMode(640, 480, 5); 
                break;
            default:
                cam.setMode(160, 120, 15); 
                break;
        } 
        removeChild(vid);           
        connectCamera();
    }
```

Comment: My question is more related to how this code behaves on Mac. Maybe a driver or an additional code is needed or maybe adobe Air just dont have that capability on Mac. the code you provided doesnt have any difference except for the FPS. Ive noted that my code works perfectly on Windows. On Mac, it looks terrible but surprisingly, Apple PhotoBooth is showing a much better display using the same camera. Any idea?

Comment: it may be because of AIR. what is the max resolution of your camera 2mpx?   try to use cam.setMode(1600, 1200,5);   is this better ?